# Giving two examples of functions with some properties.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, special-functions

This is a question from a list.

Obtain two $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying these properties:

- $f(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow 0\leq x\leq 1$;
- $g(x)=x$ if $|x|\leq 1$, and $|g(x)|<|x|$ if $|x| >1$.

Some functions that I tried are not twice derivable. I'm searching for one evolving exp, but nothing yet.

Comment: Use a "mollifier" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) to connect linear parts.

Comment: @user247327 which mollifier do I take?